# Do we have to overcome any barriers for a proof of $VP\neq VNP$ proof?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Does the same barriers of relativization, natural proofs and algebrization affect a possible $VP\neq VNP$ proof?

How do existing strategies try to overcome these?